# Select latest value of another column based on a comparison between unique keys

Tags: mysql

What I'm trying to achieve is to fetch the latest date of another column based on the same `msisdn` (if there exists more than one `msisdn` that is linked to other `imsi`s). (You can assume `imsi` is more of a unique column)

(*Tables are simplified for demonstration purposes*)

I've two tables like the following:

**operator** table

```
+--------+--------+---------------------+
|  imsi  | msisdn |    last_accessed    |
+--------+--------+---------------------+
| 74583  | 004442 | 2018-04-05 16:20:32 |
+--------+--------+---------------------+
| 94210  | 023945 | 2017-02-13 11:27:14 |
+--------+--------+---------------------+
| 59123  | 004442 | 2018-07-15 05:24:55 |
+--------+--------+---------------------+
| 61234  | 089923 | 2018-07-21 16:13:29 |
+--------+--------+---------------------+
```

**customer** table

```
+--------+--------------+---------------------+
|  imsi  |  company_id  |    business_plan    |
+--------+--------------+---------------------+
| 74583  |      FEX     |       yearly        |
+--------+--------------+---------------------+
| 94210  |      AOH     |       trial         |
+--------+--------------+---------------------+
| 59123  |      BIOI    |       monthly       |
+--------+--------------+---------------------+
| 61234  |      OOX     |       simple        |
+--------+--------------+---------------------+
```

The following result is what I aim for. If I search for `74583` it should return `2018-07-15 05:24:55`.

```
+--------+--------------+---------------------+----------------------+
|  imsi  |  company_id  |    business_plan    |  last_accessed_date  |
+--------+--------------+---------------------+----------------------+
| 74583  |      FEX     |       yearly        |  2018-07-15 05:24:55 |
+--------+--------------+---------------------+----------------------+
```

The following query returns almost what I try to achieve but does not return the latest date according to the table above.

```
SELECT 
    cust.imsi,
    cust.company_id,
    cust.business_plan,
    CASE
      WHEN
      (
        SELECT MAX(subop.last_accessed)
          FROM operator subop
            WHERE subop.msisdn = op.msisdn
              GROUP BY subop.msisdn
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      )
      THEN
        op.last_accessed
      ELSE
        'Never'
    END
      AS last_accessed_date
FROM customer cust 
  INNER JOIN operator op
    ON cust.imsi = op.imsi
WHERE cust.imsi = '74583';
```

Comment: Use order by last_accessed_date  desc  and limit 1.

Comment: Only one data is there for 74583  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try doing this using a correlated subquery in the select clause:

```
SELECT
    c.imsi,
    c.company_id,
    c.business_plan,
    (SELECT MAX(t.last_accessed) FROM operator t
     WHERE t.msisdn = o.msisdn) last_accessed_date
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN operator o
    ON c.imsi = o.imsi
WHERE c.imsi = '74583';
```

Follow the link below for a SQLFiddle demo.

### Demo

Comment: Thanks, Tim. Awesome explanation. It looks like I didn't need to do bunch of `group by`'s. I wouldn't believe it would turn out to be this short and simple. Accepted

Comment: @VolkanGüven The second query given by fthiella might be more performant than what I wrote, at least for large data sets, but it is very verbose.  Blame MySQL for not having analytic functions, which could really help here.

Comment: The correlated subquery I used is not generally favorable for performance.  But it lets us write a more concise query.

Answer (score 1):

This query will return the last_accessed_date for every imsi:

```
select
  o1.imsi,
  o1.msisdn,
  max(o2.last_accessed) as last_accessed_date
from
  operator o1 inner join operator o2
  on o1.msisdn = o2.msisdn
group by
  o1.imsi,
  o1.msisdn
```

(I am joining the operators table with itself to get the last accessed date based on the msisdn column). Then you can join this query with the customer table:

```
select
  c.imsi,
  c.company_id,
  c.business_plan,
  coalesce(l.last_accessed_date, 'Never') as last_accessed_date
from
  customer c left join (
    select
      o1.imsi,
      o1.msisdn,
      max(o2.last_accessed) as last_accessed_date
    from
      operator o1 inner join operator o2
      on o1.msisdn = o2.msisdn
    group by
      o1.imsi,
      o1.msisdn
  ) l on c.imsi = l.imsi
```

it can then be written in some different ways, but I think this is the easier to understand.

Please see a fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f080c/1

Comment: Thanks fthiella. Awesome answer with an astonishing explanation. I will however accept Tim's answer as accepted as it is more helpful and direct :) Thanks. Upvoted!

Comment: @VolkanGüven yes tim's answer is more concise and clean, i would accept his answer as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 SELECT 
      cust.imsi,
      cust.company_id,
      cust.business_plan, 
      ( 
      SELECT MAX(last_accessed) FROM operator AS a WHERE a.msisdn = op.msisdn 
      ) AS last_accessed_date 
FROM customer cust 
      INNER JOIN operator op 
      ON cust.imsi = op.imsi 
WHERE cust.imsi = '74583'
```